# Ubuntu 22.04, iBus Chinese input doesn't work with Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gtk, ibus, 22.04

In Ubuntu 22.04, with the default Nouveau driver, iBus Chinese input works fine.

But with Nvidia driver (510 and 470 tested, maybe all of them), I can only input Chinese in Qt based applications and gnome shell.

[image]

While in all the GTK based apps(like gedit, firefox etc.). I can only type letters:

[image]

What's the reason of it? How can I input Chinese while using my Nvidia graphic card?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've solved with this command:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-im-module 'ibus'

[Japanese input candidate window appears at the bottom after upgrading Ubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405101/japanese-input-candidate-window-appears-at-the-bottom-after-upgrading-ubuntu-fro)

Comment: It really works, thanks! BTW, a fully restart is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This post might be off the topic for driver related iBus issue, but for those redirected from searching results with keywords like "iBus Chinese input doesn't work in Ubuntu 22.04".

I upgraded my system from 20.04 to 22.04 last week (it was 16.04 inially installed), and the iBus almost only worked with Firefox and Konsole (yes I used KDE for a while), it didn't work with other tools like Chrome / Gnome Terminal etc. The `gsettings` command didn't help as well. I also tried to set the system language from `en-us` to `zh-cn` and it didn't help.

Then I set up a newly installed VM, iBus works perfectly almost everywhere. I guess it might be a configuration issue but I failed to find anything weird from `dconf`.

So I removed all installed desktop environments, and reinstalled Gnome Flashback (the desktop environment I use), and luckily iBus works normally again. Perhaps reinstall iBus would work as well. Hope this could be the last way to fix this iBus issue.