# Japanese input candidate window appears at the bottom after upgrading Ubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: keyboard, input-language, input-method

I upgraded from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04, and when typing in Japanese, the candidate dialog (for converting a word into kanji, or into something else) appears at the bottom of the screen instead of near the text input I'm currently typing on. How can I fix this?

More details:

It should appear next to the text input, just like before upgrading Ubuntu.

I had Ubuntu 21.10 Impish, now I have 22.04 Jammy. I fixed it with the answer I posted.

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 21 does exist. The one I had is called ubuntu 21 Impish. Now I have 22.04 jammy. Rock n roll!

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 is *impish indri*, and it's a *year.month* format release and **not** a *year* format release.  Ubuntu releases using the *year* format are *snap* only, thus cannot use the `apt`, `dpkg` and *like deb* package format commands.  The *year* based releases with 10 years of supported life (*without need for ESM*) and are closest to the LTS releases of *year.month* format releases. Ubuntu 21.10 or *impish indri* is a non-LTS and the last non-LTS before the LTS in the development cycle that started with 20.10 and ends with 22.04 LTS and not a *year* product

Comment: Canonical/Ubuntu introduced the *year* products in 2016 and are used for server systems only, useful for IoT, appliance & devices, and also cloud use (they're faster to *spin* up).  When you upgrade to the next release; no user-packages change (a benefit of the *snap* system which *deb* packages does not allow for)....  They are **not** intended for desktop use (desktop packages are generally packaged as *deb* packages being intended for the *year.format* products) and the *year* format products are not supported by *flavors* of Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes I agree, and the Ubuntu I had is Ubuntu 21 Impish. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by executing:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-im-module 'ibus'
```

This fixed the problem permanently, including after rebooting.

Solution found here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/im-config/+bug/1969637